# Rackspace Cloud Site & ASP.NET Web API

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the ASP.NET Web API in my site. When I add it to my Rackspace cloud site, the assemblies in my web.config aren't recognized. I'm getting configuration errors, such as:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Rackspace Support says I need to add the dll files. Does this mean they don't support ASP.NET Web API? Is it possible to add the dll files myself? If yes, where do I get them from?

TIA

Comment: My understanding is that Rackspace Cloud gives you admin access over a virtual server.  Thus it would be your responsibility to install the relevent frameworks, etc.

Comment: @KirkWoll I thought that was only for Cloud Servers? I have a Cloud Site account.

Comment: ah, yes, those are a lot more limited.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by copying the DLL files from my C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cloud site is set to .NET 4.0. Only a recent update allow you to select 4.0 (before all ASP.NET sites defaulted to 3.5).